# De onde vieram os termos "Xuxinha" e "Rabicó" para se referir a prendedor de cabelo?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, português-brasileiro

Cotidianamente ouvimos as mulheres aqui do Brasil chamarem o prendedor de cabelo, de "Xuxinha", "Rabicó", "Elastiquinho", etc.

E fiquei me perguntando, de onde surgiu isso, não tem lógica.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Será que *xuxinha* tem que ver com a Xuxa do xou? [Ela aparece quase sempre de xuxinha](https://www.google.pt/search?q=xou+da+xuxa&num=50&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYs77c-IvNAhXFrRoKHcg2B4cQ_AUIBygB&biw=1242&bih=585)

Comment: Oia.. antigamente realmente ela aparecia sempre de **xuxinha** faz algum sentido sim ... mas será?

Comment: Não sei. Sabes se a palavra já era usada com este sentido antes da Xuxa aparecer de xuxinha? A palavra não vem no meu Houaiss de 2002, o que sugere que é um termo recente.

Comment: Outra coisa, não seria melhor ter duas perguntas separadas, uma para *xuxinha*, outra para *rabicó*? É que é possível ter uma resposta para uma sem ter para a outra. Acabei de postar uma pergunta no meta sobre o assunto.

Comment: Realmente, vou acompanhar sua pergunta la, o duro é duplicar a questão somente substituindo os termos, seria quase que duplicar... interessante.. vamos aguardar, iria remover o termo Rabicó, mas vamos aguardar o Meta. Obrigado Jjacinto.

Comment: tem uma marca desses prendedores de cabelo que é xuquinha, e parece que chuquinha seria outro nome; xuxinha é por causa da xuxa mesmo

Comment: @AndréLyra, `chuquinha` é um negocio para dar líquidos para bebe, aproposito não é recomendado. Mas realmente, xuxinha deve ter vindo da xuxa mesmo...

Comment: Eu sei que chuquinha é a mamadeira de água e chás para bebês; mas procure no google imagens e verá a marca xuquinha para o prendedor de cabelo, e chuquinhas para o penteado da xuxa com xuxinhas.

Comment: Para *rabicó* tenho apenas uma especulação: [*rabicó*](http://www.aulete.com.br/rabic%C3%B3) é um animal sem cauda ou só com um bocado de cauda. Poderia ser adotado para designar um tufo de cabelo curto (à semelhança de *rabo-de-cavalo, rabicho*) e a partir daí o elástico para o prender. Há também a personagem infantil *Marquês de Rabicó* (assim chamado porque tem apenas uma cauda curta) que poderia facilitar a adoção do termo por crianças. Mas eu acho mesmo que deveriam ser duas perguntas separadas: a resposta a uma não tem que ver com a resposta à outra.

Comment: Para falar com franqueza, nunca ouvi o termo "xuxinha" para esse tipo de prendedor de cabelo. Sempre ouvi "chuquinha".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Xuxinha*** vem da artista brasileira Xuxa Meneghel e dos programas infantis que ela apresentou na televisão brasileira nos anos oitenta e noventa, em que ela aparecia quase sempre com xuxinhas no cabelo.

Xuxa Meneghel nasceu em 1963, recebendo o nome Maria da Graça Meneghel. Foi o irmão que imediatamente a apelidou de Xuxa. O apelido pegou e em 1988 integrou oficialmente o nome da artista, que passou a ser Maria da Graça Xuxa Meneghel. Em 1983 começou a apresentar o Clube da Criança na antiga TV Manchete, ganhou fama, e em 1986 mudou-se para a Globo para apresentar o Xou da Xuxa, outro programa infantil, que fez um sucesso estrondoso e ditou a moda infantil. [(Wikipédia.)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuxa)

Não encontrei qualquer indício que a palavra *xuxa* ou *xuxinha* existisse antes da Xuxa Meneghel. Existe a palavra homófona [*chucha* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/chucha), mas não parece ter qualquer relação. Mas *xuxinha* aprece logo nos anos oitenta, mas de acordo com esta [sinopse do *Almanaque da TV* de Bia Bruna e Rixa, 2007](http://www.ciadoslivros.com.br/almanaque-da-tv-280917-p24289), parece ter começado por designar os tufos de cabelo presos pelo elástico e não o próprio elástico:

[image]

É possível que o nome tenha sido também influenciado por [*maria-chiquinha*](http://www.aulete.com.br/maria-chiquinha). Tudo à volta da Xuxa tinha que ter *x*: depois do álbum *Xou da Xuxa* veio em 1987 o [*Xegundo Xou da Xuxa*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xegundo_Xou_da_Xuxa), que incluía a faixa *Rexeita da Xuxa*, e os balões em forma de salsicha no Clube da Criança eram [*salxuxas*](http://bloggerxuper.blogspot.pt/2008/07/clube-da-criana-estrutura-do-programa.html). Mudar *chiquinha* para *xuxinha* não parece nada de extraordinário.

Entretanto *xuxinha* passou a designar o próprio elástico. Isto vem referido no [Almanaque da TV Globo, de Marcel Souto Maior, 2006](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kuUuAAAAYAAJ&q=xuxinhas&dq=xuxinhas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKiIyDm5TNAhWNyRoKHSBZBLsQ6AEISDAF):

> **BOTAS BRANCAS E PRENDEDORES PARA OS CABELOS:** Peças mais vendidas nas lojas O bicho comeu, de Xuxa.
> **XUXINHAS:** Assim passaram a ser conhecidos os prendedores de cabelo, usados para fazer maria-chiquinhas e rabos de cavalo copiados da apresentadora e das suas paquitas.

O autor não diz quando foi que isso aconteceu, mas [neste artigo online](http://www.vilamulher.com.br/moda/estilo-e-tendencias/a-xuxinha-dos-anos-90-esta-de-volta-14-1-32-2630.html) afirma-se que esse nome já era corrente nos anos noventa:

> **A XUXINHA DOS ANOS 90 ESTÁ DE VOLTA**
>
> Quem se lembra daqueles elásticos de cabelo bem fofos feitos de tecido, de vários tipos, como veludo, por exemplo. Pois é, eles voltaram. Quem viveu a época conheceu o acessório com o nome de “**xuxinha**”

A primeira ocorrência de *xuxinha* (de cabelo) que encontrei é de 2001:
[image]

Entretanto, *xuxinha* ainda não aparece nos dicionários, nem mesmo nos online, nem no [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum da Língua Portuguesa](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?sel=contain&action=simplesearch&base=form&query=xuxinha) nem no [Vocabulário Ortgráfico da Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario).

Answer (score 3):

O termo provavelmente vem do **francês** "**chouchou**"

> Anneau de tissu froncé par un élastique et servant à tenir les
>   cheveux. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksjFY.jpg)

"Anel de tecido reunido por um elástico e usado para segurar o cabelo" (tradução livre)

A pronúncia do termo é como o português "chuchu" (legume) e nossa adaptação de escrita deve ter ficado "**xuxu**". Daí então foi derivado o termo "**xuxinha**".

[image]

[[1] Dictionnaires de Français Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chouchou/187796?q=chouchou#11045353)